# Update database using 'update_attributes' through 'has_many'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

I'm having a problem getting my first app (I'm a total newbie) to save a new associated record. I have two models (users and pictures) with a has_many/belongs_to association. I have set up the userController so that it can create a new picture as below:

```
  def new_picture
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @picture = @user.pictures.build
  end

  def create_picture
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @picture = @user.pictures.build(params[:picture])
    if @picture.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your picture was successfully added."
      redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @user.id
    else
      render :template => "new_picture"
    end
  end
```

and I use

```
<%= link_to("add picture", :action => 'new_picture', :id => @user.id) if current_user %>
```

to add a new one. But I'd also like to be able to edit. So I updated the usercontroller with some new code:

```
  def edit_picture
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @picture = @user.pictures.find(params[:id])
  end
  # When the user clicks the save button update record

  def update_picture
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @picture = @user.pictures.find(params[:picture])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @picture.update_attributes(params[:picture])
        flash[:notice] = "Your picture was successfully updated."
        redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @user.id
      else
        render :template => "new_picture"
      end
    end
  end
```

and added the edit link to show.erb:

```
<%= link_to("edit picture", :action => 'edit_picture', :id => picture.id) if current_user %>
```

It loads the edit form fine, with the data all in the right place, but on save all it's doing is giving me the error 'ArgumentError in UsersController#update_picture' with a bunch of Unknown key(s) from my pictures table.

Could somebody explain why? I feel like there is one piece of the jigsaw I haven't quite understood here....

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: View code is as follows:

```
<h1>New picture for <%= @user.name %></h1>
<% form_for :picture, @picture, :html => { :multipart => true }, :url => {:action => 'update_picture', :id => @user.id} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Off-topic.For future use this when finding parameters. Instead of "@user = User.find(params[:id])", use this "@user = User.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?", params[:id]])". This will help escape unwanted characters in the parameters you receive.

Comment: Sorry - is this off-topic? I can edit it if so - where should it be?

Comment: sorry, i just meant that my comment is not answering your question specifically, i just gave a recommendation when you filter params.

Comment: I think he/she meant the comment was off-topic. This is also off-topic: `@user = User.find(current_user.id)` could be replaced with `@user = current_user`. Back on topic: please post your view code as well, I suspect that's where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry @jimworm, just added the view code from the form (I assume you don't need the whole thing)

Answer (score 1):

Can't seem to see your problem in the view code, however you can do the same thing more elegantly (RESTful) as a nested route. That way you might be able to see the problem more clearly.

config/routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    resources :pictures
  end
end
```

app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_picture, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @picture.update_attributes params[:picture]
      flash[:notice] = "Your picture was successfully updated."
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  protected
  def find_picture
    @picture = current_user.pictures.find params[:id]
  end
end
```

app/views/pictures/edit.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @picture] do |f| %>
<!-- some stuff -->
<% end %>
```

and to link to your edit form:

```
<%= link_to_if current_user, 'edit picture',
                edit_user_picture_path(:user => current_user, :id => picture) %>
```

Comment: Hmmm, it tells me that edit_user_picture_path is an undefined method when I load the show page? Is this a problem with the scaffold?

Comment: Check what the path helper should be with `rake routes`.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem... did you put the routes in?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding 'accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures to the user model, and then do

```
<%= form_for @user do |form| %>
  .. user fields

  <%= form.fields_for :pictures do |picture_form| %> 

    .. picture fields

  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

in the view.

Another option is to create a new controller for the pictures. That may be simpler.